# Stored Procedure execution time not coming correct

Tags: performance, oracle, stored-procedures, timestamp

Hi was trying to find out time taken for the execution of an API call: here is the code

```
DECLARE  
l_time timestamp;   
l_lapsetime  VARCHAR2(100);  
BEGIN  
select systimestamp into l_time from dual;      
--here goes my API call  
select to_char((systimestamp-l_time),'HH24:MI:SS') into l_lapsetime from dual;    
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Time taken  ' || l_lapsetime);  
END;
```

I was expecting result to be coming in milliseconds but I’m getting output as:

```
Time taken  +000000000 10:30:00.016938000
```

Isn’t this time too much??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you substract two timestamps, the result is of type [INTERVAL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements001.htm#i78291).

[TO_CHAR](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions179.htm#i1006717) is not defined on interval, what happens here is that Oracle performs a standard implicit conversion from INTERVAL to VARCHAR2, ignoring your second argument.

If you want to convert INTERVAL to characters, use [EXTRACT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions050.htm#i1017161):

```
    SELECT extract(hour FROM v_interval) || ':'
           || extract(minute FROM v_interval) || ':'
           || extract(SECOND FROM v_interval)
      FROM (SELECT &timestamp2 - &timestamp1 v_interval FROM dual)
```